How to disable Horizontal Scrollbar in Mudblazor Datagrid
We have requirement to not let Horizontal Scrollbar show up in MudBlazor DataGrid when screen size is reduced, we can shrink column width till it switches to CardView. I have tried HorizontalScrollbar="false" but that does not help.
<MudDataGrid @ref="_dataGrid" T="InspectionTask" Items="@EquipmentDetailsPersistence.InspectionTasks" Filterable="false" FilterMode="DataGridFilterMode.Simple"
             Hover="true" QuickFilter="@QuickFilter" SortMode="SortMode.Single" Outlined="false" Elevation="0"
             FilterCaseSensitivity="DataGridFilterCaseSensitivity.CaseInsensitive" Striped="true">
    <ToolBarContent>
        <MudTextField @bind-Value="_searchString" FullWidth="true" Placeholder="Search" Adornment="Adornment.Start" Immediate="true"
                      Variant="Variant.Outlined" AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Search" IconSize="Size.Medium" Class="m-0">
        </MudTextField>
    </ToolBarContent>
    <Columns>
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.TaskId" Title="Task" Filterable="true"/>
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.LastInspectionDate" Title="Last Inspection" Filterable="true" Format="@dateFormat"/>
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.NextCalculatedInspectionDate" Title="Next Inspection" Format="@dateFormat" Filterable="true" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.NextScheduledInspectionDate" Title="Next Scheduled Inspection" Format="@dateFormat" Filterable="true" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.MapComments" Title="Comments" Filterable="true"/>
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.OperatingImpact" Title="Operating Impact" Filterable="true"/>
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.ExemptStatus" Title="Exempt" Filterable="true"/>
    </Columns>
    <PagerContent>
        <MudDataGridPager T="InspectionTask"/>
    </PagerContent>
</MudDataGrid>


A simple option might be setting the Breakpoint. The default is Xs setting it to Md would allow it to switch to the card view earlier instead scrolling
